# Default Value in Destructured Function Parameter Causes ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, firebase, testing, default-value, destructuring

I needed to set a default value for `db` in my CRUD functions for testing purposes and encountered a strange behaviour, I could not figure out yet. Consider the following code:

```
import { db } from './firebase'

function getUsers({ db = db }) {
  try {
    return db
    ...
```

Now, when I use the function in my tests, there is no problem, since I invoke the function in my test file with a test db. But the real app should be able to fall back on the default value and call the function without any params. 
But here, I encounter the error: `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'db' before initialization`. I have no idea why this happens.

I found a workaround by renaming the parameter. But still, I would really love to know what is happening here. Anyone have an idea?

Workarond:

```
import * as firebase from './firebase'

function getUsers({ db = firebase.db }) {
  try {
    return db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way scope works in function declaration parameter lists. The scope of the default argument value context *includes* the parameter list itself (well, the ones already declared).  Thus the `db` parameter shadows the relatively global symbol from the import.

You could also workaround the problem by changing the parameter name:

```
function getUsers({database = db})
```

The scope works that way so that it's possible to use parameters earlier in the parameter list in expressions for parameters later in the list:

```
function something(a, b = a + 1)
```

Calling that function like `something(0)` would set `b` to 1.

Oh, and re-reading your question, initializing a parameter to itself doesn't work because, well, it doesn't make sense; if the parameter isn't there in a function call, then it's `undefined`, so having the default value be `undefined` explicitly is incorrect.

Comment: That is a very clear and helpful explanation. Thank you for the prompt answer! Yes, I also had the suggested workaround in place, but then changed it to the afore mentioned, because in my tests I would then have to invoke the function with `database: db` - which I somehow didn't like.